# Quick or Quickly: “How to Install a PHP Extension: Quick and Easy”

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, flat-adverbs

Let’s say I have this title:

*How to Install a PHP Extension: **Quick** and **Easy***

Should I say *quick and easy* or *quickly and easily*?

Why?

Comment: It depends on the tone you want to convey. In an informal register, this works; someone will claim it's an obvious elision of 'How to Install a PHP Extension: the Quick and Easy Way'. Informally, sentence fragments / ellipses are usually quite acceptable if they don't bring about ambiguity. If you want a formal version, drop most of the capitals and the colon, and use the adverbs. (But you still don't have a true sentence.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like your implied noun. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @bib: Someone will claim that the claim that "it's an obvious elision of 'How to Install a PHP Extension: the Quick and Easy Way' " is spurious.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of [56563](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56563/using-short-adjectives-as-adverbs-such-as-easy-short). That question is about using adjectives such as *easy* like adverbs in sentences. This question is about using them in titles, which don't follow the same rules as sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms *Quick and Easy* modify *Install*. Technically, since *install* is a verb, they should be adverbs - *Quickly and Easily*.

However titles have a life of their own, and they often exist on a different planet than we prescriptivist grammarians. You get a lot of latitude.

Additionally, the adjectival forms have an implied noun to modify: *installation*.  You are suggesting the *installation will be quick and easy*.

To be a purist, make them adverbs. Or you can leave it punchy.

Comment: I like 'leave it punchy'.

Comment: also, don't be a purist.

Answer (score 2):

Quick is what we call a flat adverb...Do it nice and easy, nice and slow, drive quick, stay safe...these are all grammatically correct.

I'd keep the title.

Comment: The question is clearly a dup (we get "flat adverb" questions every other week, it seems). But yours seems to be the only answer clearly acknowledging that *both forms are grammatically "correct"* in OP's context, so +1

Comment: Here's a nice video from merriam Webster about flat adverbs:http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0030-flatadverbs.htm

Comment: Nice link. Disappointing to see that even after having it spelt out as plain (-ly ?!) as day, the first comment there says *for the most part, flat adverbs are colloquial, and would not be acceptable in what we consider formal writing*. That commenter obviously didn't try hard (-ly) to grasp the point being made.

Comment: Note: _safe_ in “Stay safe” is the odd one out here since it is not a flat adverb, but a simple adjective. _Stay_ is a linking verb, and _safe_ is its predicate, i.e., a noun phrase. In the other sentences you give, the (flat) adverbs modify the verb and are true adverbs. You can do it nicely and drive slowly, but you cannot _*stay safely_.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet You can, English being what it is, _stay safely in your home_. And _stay safely in certain parts of Elbonia_. Though perhaps the first example is a prepositional-phrase modifier usage rather than an adverbial one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth True; what I meant was that you cannot ‘stay safely’ with the same meaning as ‘stay safe’. _Safe_ doesn't work as a flat adverb with _stay_, only as an adjective.

Comment: @Janus But I could not resist pointing out yet another quirk of the incredible language we know and love. Hate. Use. Think we can master.

Answer (score 0):

Your are modifying an infinitive so you need adverbs, so you'd be on unassailable ground with *Quickly and Easily*, but *Quick and Easy* might be snappier in a title.  You could make the issue disappear with either "PHP Extension Installation, Quick and Easy" or "Quick and Easy Installation of PHP Extension."

Answer (score 0):

"Quick" is an adjective and "quickly" is an adverb, so you should use "quickly" to modify "do".

However, "quick as possible" is often used in everyday English.
http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/ask-teacher/132007-quick-quickly.html

But I suggest you to use fast and easy. See [this link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quickly).

**Quick** can be adverb or adjective.